# sleep sort in c++ 11

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

guys i am  thinking about one sorting method,it is called sleep sort

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(int c, char **v)
{
    while (--c > 1 && !fork());
    sleep(c = atoi(v[c]));
    printf("%d\n", c);
    wait(0);
    return 0;
}
```

i dont understand  one thing,what is fork equivalent in c++ 11?i meant new version of c++?i could write wait function like this

```
void wait ( int seconds ){
    clock_t endwait;
    endwait = clock () + seconds * CLOCKS_PER_SEC ;
    while (clock() < endwait) {}
}
```

but what about  fork()?
i have try following code

```
#include<iostream>
#include<time.h>
using namespace std;;

void wait ( int seconds ){
    clock_t endwait;
    endwait = clock () + seconds * CLOCKS_PER_SEC ;
    while (clock() < endwait) {}
}

void Sort(int c,int a[])
{
    while(--c>1)
    {
        wait(c=a[c]);
        cout<<c<<"  ";
    }
 }

int main()
{
    int a[]={1, 3, 2, 11, 6, 4};
    int c=5;
    Sort(c,a);
    wait(0);

    return 0;
}
```

but it does not give me sorted output,it outputs like 6 4 1 and finishes,so please tell me how to  correct it?

Comment: but it does not prints other  members

Comment: http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Sleep_sort#C

Comment: I think you fundamentally don't understand what the original code does.

Comment: fork() is a system call.  The timing of the sleeps is important for it to actually sort the way you want.  Either use fork in the C++ version or create threads instead.  There is a new thread API in the latest C & C++ standards or you could simply use pthreads.

Comment: but i have not  linux system installed,could i write it on windows?

Comment: @AleksiBeriashvili: In Windows you'll want to use the Windows threading library, unless you want to try to set up and use a posix environment there.

Comment: ok clear,it means i can't use  threads  yes which are defined in c++ 11?

Comment: @Aleksi : Yes, you can of course use C++11's `std::thread` or `boost::thread`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working implementation in C++ using Win32:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

DWORD threadFunc(LPVOID param)
{
    long val = (long)param;
    Sleep((int)val * 1000);
    cout << val << " ";
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    HANDLE handles[6];
    int arr[] = {1, 3, 2, 11, 6, 4};

    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    {
        handles[i] = CreateThread(NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)&threadFunc, 
                                  (LPVOID)arr[i], 0, NULL);
    }

    WaitForMultipleObjects(6, handles, 1, INFINITE);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You cannot simply delay as in your `wait()` function; this works by creating a new process (via `fork()`) for each argument and letting each sleep in parallel; your proposal would have each element sleep in series, thus not giving the illusion of a sort.

As to `what is fork equivalent in c++ 11?` -- fork() is not specific to C or C++; it's an operating system provided function.

Comment: so it means it is only for linux systems?i understood what code does

Answer (score 1):

You've not understood the point. The waits must run *in parallel* (triggered by fork, which creates a new thread for each item).

Comment: Agree. Absolutely. (Well, a new process implies a new thread, doesn't it?)

Comment: Yes, but also a new stack, new heap, new context, maybe a new process group, session, etc... All of which muddy the waters a bit more... ;-)

Comment: We probably agree that SleepSort is not the most efficient sorting algorithm on earth anyway. Runtime, however, should be O(n)! That would be pretty good. Where's my mistake?

Comment: I think the mistake is that O(...) notation is usually based on the assumption of a single processor and/or serial execution. Trying to use it to analyze parallel algorithms is considerably trickier, and by my estimation, SleepSort should probably be classified as O(n^2) - O(n) per process, but there's n processes... Or maybe not... And the space overhead is pretty significant, too...

Answer (score 1):

Although there are more things to talk about, I'm only going to answer your main question.

You have set `c=5` although you have 6 numbers, and you have `while(--c>1)` so, if you calculate, it only runs the loop 3 times, because if you add the `--` before the operator it will first substract 1 and then compare.

- `c=5`
- `while(--c>1)` [substract 1 of 5=4 and check if is bigger than 1] //runs it
- `while(--c>1)` [substract 1 of 4=3 and check if is bigger than 1] //runs it
- `while(--c>1)` [substract 1 of 3=2 and check if is bigger than 1] //runs it
- `while(--c>1)` [substract 1 of 2=1 and check if is bigger than 1] //doesn't run it

You have to change `c` to the quantity of numbers you have: `c=6`, then change the `while` loop like this: `while(c-->0)`

Answer (score 0):

Cross-platform version. Supports negative numbers!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <algorithm>

template< typename It >
void sleepSort( const It& begin, const It& end )
{
    if ( begin == end )
        return;
    const auto [min, max] = std::minmax_element( begin, end );
    for ( auto it = begin; it != end; ++it )
    {
        std::thread( [min = *min, i = *it]
            {
                std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::milliseconds( i - min ) );
                std::cout << i << std::endl;
            } ).detach();
    }
    std::this_thread::sleep_for( std::chrono::milliseconds( *max - *min + 1 ) );
}

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    std::vector<int> v = { 20, 5, 15, 10, -5, };
    sleepSort( v.begin(), v.end() );

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> -5 5 10 15 20